# .next() and .prev() to loop through divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use simple jQuery to perform slide through `div` elements. But how do I use `next()` and `prev()` to go through slide items?

The problem is when you go next, next, next, next. The `div` finally stops and doesn't show; it doesn't loop round back to the first `div`.

This is what I've got so far:

```js
$("p.right").click(function() {
  $(".item.active").removeClass("active").next(".item").addClass("active").show();
});
$("p.left").click(function() {
  $(".item.active").removeClass("active").prev(".item").addClass("active").show();
});
```

```css
Section {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: blue;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

p.left {
  top: 0px;
  left: 20px;
}

p.right {
  top: 0px;
  right: 20px;
}

div {
  display: none;
}

div.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="item active">First Item</div>
  <div class="item">Second Item</div>
  <div class="item">Third Item</div>
  <div class="item">Last Item</div>
  <p class="right">N</p>
  <p class="left">P</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay with some thinking about this, I've finally come up with the answer myself. Here it is if anybody would like to know how I've done it.

I was inspired by [Erik Grosskurth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47310805/3296661) post

```js
$("p.right").click(function(){
  if ($(".item.active").next(".item").length){
   $(".item.active").removeClass("active").next(".item").addClass("active");
  } else {
   $(".item.active").removeClass("active");
   $(".item:first").addClass("active");
  }
 });
 
 $("p.left").click(function(){
  if ($(".item.active").prev(".item").length){
   $(".item.active").removeClass("active").prev(".item").addClass("active");
  } else {
   $(".item.active").removeClass("active");
   $(".item").last().addClass("active");
  }
 });
```

```css
Section{
position: relative;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
}
p{
position: absolute;
margin: 0px;
padding: 5px 10px;
background: blue;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 100%;
}
p.left{
  top: 0px;
  left: 20px;
}
p.right{
  top: 0px;
  right: 20px;
}

div{
 display: none;
}
div.active{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="item active">First Item</div>
  <div class="item">Second Item</div>
  <div class="item">Third Item</div>
  <div class="item">Last Item</div>
  <p class="right">N</p>
  <p class="left">P</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try some iteration of this:

```
if (this.is('div:last-child')) { 
   //Start carousel over at first child
}else {
   // On to the next one
}
```

Comment: Nice solution!!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check if the index of `.active` is the first or last item.

```js
$(function() {
  var numSlides = $('div.active').parent().find('div').length;

  $("p.right").click(function() {
    if( $('div.active').index()+1 == numSlides ) {
      $('div.active').removeClass('active').parent().find('div:first').addClass('active');
    }
    else {
      $("div.active").removeClass("active").next("div").addClass("active");
    }
  });
  $("p.left").click(function() {
    if( $('div.active').index() == 0 ) {
      $('div.active').removeClass('active').parent().find('div:last').addClass('active');
    }
    else {
      $("div.active").removeClass("active").prev("div").addClass("active").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
Section {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: blue;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

p.left {
  top: 0px;
  left: 20px;
}

p.right {
  top: 0px;
  right: 20px;
}

div {
  display: none;
}

div.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="active">First Item</div>
  <div>Second Item</div>
  <div>Third Item</div>
  <div>Last Item</div>
  <p class="right">N</p>
  <p class="left">P</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a working solution to loop around when you get to either end of the list of items -- though the `p.left` function won't go from first to last here because of the way the SO snippet is coded (using `<div>`s).

The `p.right` function works as intended, and the `p.left` function would work similarly, in a "normal" web environment.

```js
$("p.right").click(function() {
  if ($("div.active").next("div").text() == "") {
    // if at the last item, loop around
    $("div.active").removeClass("active");
    $("div").first().addClass("active").show();
  } else {
    // else go to the next one
    $("div.active").removeClass("active").next("div").addClass("active").show();
  }
});
$("p.left").click(function() {
  if ($("div.active").prev("div").text() == "") {
    // if at the first item, loop around
    $("div.active").removeClass("active");
    $("div").last().addClass("active").show();
  } else {
    // else go to the previous one
    $("div.active").removeClass("active").prev("div").addClass("active").show();
  }
});
```

```css
Section {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: blue;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

p.left {
  top: 0px;
  left: 20px;
}

p.right {
  top: 0px;
  right: 20px;
}

div {
  display: none;
}

div.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="active">First Item</div>
  <div>Second Item</div>
  <div>Third Item</div>
  <div>Last Item</div>
  <p class="right">N</p>
  <p class="left">P</p>
</section>
```

Comment: `Prev()` isn't working. I would test before releasing

Comment: @ChrisBeckett Please see my note above.  `prev()` doesn't work here -- and only on the first element -- because of SO's snippet structure and how it adds `<div>`s that you don't interact with.  It works fine on the other elements, and also works fine in a typical web environment.

Comment: Ahhh my bad, sorry i've only just seen that note.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a partial solution to detect whether you are going past the last div (or before the first div) here:

https://jsfiddle.net/cewqotsv/1/

Essentially, you can detect whether there are any divs after the "active" one as such

```
if($("div.active").next("div").length == 0){
  //do nothing
}
```